# strange behavior of the evaluate expression statement $(()) inside "for" loop conditional statements

Tags: bash

Do somebody know why this loop iterates twice less than it should.
Here is the code:

```
var1='000000001010111111111010101011111111111110101110'
var2='1010111111111010101011111111111111111111'

if [[ ${#var1} -gt ${#var2} ]] ; then
 for (( vb2=0 ; vb2<$((${#var1} - ${#var2})) ; vb2++ )) ; do
  var2=0"$var2"
 done
fi
echo $var1
echo $var2
```

I would really appreciate any help

Comment: thanks everyone. the matter is solved.

Comment: a note for printf solution. it seem to print undesirable additional 0's when variable is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is because of this part:

```
vb2<$((${#var1} - ${#var2}))
```

When you do the comparison, you are re-evaluating the length of var2 again. What you really want to do is set this once before the loop, e.g.

```
...
diff=$(( ${#var1} - ${#var2} ))
for (( vb2=0 ; vb2<$diff ; vb2++ )) ; do
 ...
```

`printf` is a better way to do this, maybe. Here is a printf example:

```
var1='000000001010111111111010101011111111111110101110'
var2='1010111111111010101011111111111111111111'

if [[ ${#var1} -gt ${#var2} ]] ; then
 diff=$(( ${#var1} - ${#var2} ))
 var2=$( printf "%0${diff}d%s" 0 $var2 )
fi
echo $var1
echo $var2
```

Comment: tricky. how this could be done via "for" means exclusively? thanks anyway, it have shed some light over this matter.

Comment: If you want to use `for`, you could always build a string of zeros instead of modifying `var2` in the loop, then prepend the string of zeros to `var2` after the loop. There's more than one way to do it, but I would use `printf`, personally.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that both the loop index and the loop end point change with each iteration of the `for` loop.

The code below is simpler.  It replaces both the `if` statement and `for` statement with a single `while` loop:

```
var1='000000001010111111111010101011111111111110101110'
var2='1010111111111010101011111111111111111111'
while ((${#var1} - ${#var2} > 0))
do
  var2=0"$var2"
done
echo $var1
echo $var2
```

Comment: yes thanks. i guess i'll use something looking like this one.

Comment: and by the way, what do double parenthesis do?

Comment: @user3694243 The double parenthesis puts `bash` in arithmetic mode.  Without them, `bash` would think that `${#var1}` was a command to execute and that `>` was the symbol for output redirection.

Comment: could not i use $(()) in here?

Comment: @user3694243 Use `$((...))` when you want to return the result of the calculation.  Example: `echo "We are missing $((${#var1} - ${#var2})) characters`.  By contrast, `((...))` without the `$` is useful, among other things, for doing tests like in the `while` loop above.

Comment: it seem i used [[ $(()) -ne 0 ]] before, instead of (()). works the same.

Comment: Yes, that works also.  In that case, the advantage of `((...))` just that it is shorter.

Comment: what can i say, standards are my passion